# Calling openssl_pkey_export() twice with the same passphrase gives different results

Tags: php, openssl, encryption-asymmetric

I have basic knowledge on asymmetric cryptography but I'm a newbie regarding OpenSSL PHP Extension and I'm confused after executing the following piece of code (please, note that `openssl_pkey_new()` is called just once but `openssl_pkey_export()` with passphrase is called twice):

```
// Based on:
// PHP: openssl_pkey_new - Manual
// => https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.openssl-pkey-new.php#111769
$config=array(
    "digest_alg" => "sha512",
    "private_key_bits" => 4096,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
);
// Create the private and public key
$res=openssl_pkey_new($config);
// Extract the private key from $res
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey);
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKeyEnc1, "12345678");
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKeyEnc2, "12345678");
print_r($privKeyEnc1); /* Output 1 */
print_r($privKeyEnc2); /* Output 2 */
```

I run it using `php -a` and I figure out that Output 1 and Output 2 (`$privKeyEnc1` and `$privKeyEnc2`) are different (I post first and last characters only):

Output 1 (`$privKeyEnc1`):

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJnDBOBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wQTApBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwHAQIu9pGQ4UYhHMCAggA
...
b/Jzga55d9CZAez70XZ1IcDlqhtfCS0Q7+RDwdXgsAd9IYrZaVKBrUOxhaSc/Xe8
9GBsV9M67b7uyJ1wAeEpJw==
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Output 2 (`$privKeyEnc2`):

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJnDBOBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wQTApBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwHAQIiNaCw3b9l9wCAggA
...
bOL2WGBOymb6db0G5/IdIs7zQx6aQjOtoFx4hm0cY4YmEmNKKdiXOoVpRZT4SBRw
t8ksuWHoESag0z4NETpetw==
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Is this wrong or is it normal behavior? **Can anybody explain in detail why this occurs?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP code creates a PEM encoded encrypted PKCS#8 key. During encryption, *random* values for salt and IV are generated, which result in a different encryption each time even for the same (unencrypted) key, which is why the encrypted keys differ.

---

To illustrate this, consider the following encrypted key generated with your code (for simplicity a 512 bit key is used, in practice the key size must be >= 2048 bits for security reasons):

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

With an ASN.1 parser, e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/, the following decoding results:

[image]

This provides the following information about the encrypted key:

- The symmetric key applied for encryption is derived using PBKDF2. In addition to the password, HMAC/SHA256, the *randomly* generated salt 0xCE37F7B93B9A3924 and an iteration count of 2048 are applied.
- The encryption itself takes place with des-EDE3-CBC, i.e. with Triple DES in CBC mode, which implies a 192 bits key. The *randomly* generated IV 0xD681F9C689D44C3B is used. The byte sequence 0x946B99249E... is the ciphertext.

The random salt results in a different symmetric key for each encryption, even with identical password. Both, the random symmetric key and the random IV cause a different ciphertext i.e. different encrypted key for each encryption, which strengthens security.

---

Test:

The logic described above can be easily tested by decrypting the key. For decryption ciphertext, password, salt and IV are required, e.g.:

```php
$encryptedPkcs8 = hex2bin("946b99249e94028eecf411eb632c72766629c3a794927efb9cebc9a57f07da90756418462f4a622c8d02e56cbc9830f46b0d6558c1f7d31f2ddc756b5a69390e2dce784097c75bedc618b11130d406f24e0439739f15402342554a865924b4f734a8a1903d764053084e76bf1d3f4b035f0ce5255bf347f5e430432dd601ec7b9983d2c0e65fb93974d16cfb52e244e07697012dc5eb959be26b7b9e6b4b9358441443d4173c4787bc695f10c5146d9237588c51abd0169eb5f78ed8ec94be2e188ff81de044488038589b2bcab6b0124664cd839cdfa2ac0fa67ae404fe652db325b1e0a4a29d406f7c501723ee38f25915dfe5a47bbc8a33e062cc82bab9afb8a009f7de88fb55dfd2162ab4fe1d2bb5713f3af44c793286af5c01c7ae32f8f873b88b176aba503ae9cd50ddab9ea05897245463a3d407d5cf27c0e549c82f29eb6c79bcbeca0e5a0d27a38dc759c82debc17f87bdd54e710f263c39fa66b8"); 
$tripleDesKey = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", "12345678", hex2bin("ce37f7b93b9a3924"), 2048, 24, true);
$pkcs8Der = openssl_decrypt($encryptedPkcs8, "des-EDE3-CBC", $tripleDesKey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, hex2bin("d681f9c689d44c3b"));
$pkcs8Pem = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" . chunk_split(base64_encode($pkcs8Der), 64, "\n") . "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
print($pkcs8Pem . PHP_EOL);
```

which gives the following PKCS#8 key:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBVQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT8wggE7AgEAAkEAzw++K1mInb7pX8tH
LEwE/ZCpoRXcKvwCYPCVK4Rfor4Wt32BrdHGY6d8tTFFAdGKH5fPSyVDQWPBjyEM
I51+1wIDAQABAkBx7UyKF4I2oSNQ5MztT4pzZZQfoKJ6OByq79RzlCr2pDkEQHw+
PIFKOXXa0jKPFD9HqmNTyCJBXkrDg40RpThxAiEA6Vgs+h1wpR4ZD+woJSFhRkqZ
QY/rKZNDPL0aZZE0cxkCIQDjKkyZmxDfrns0wua9Mvp5mqOWjgdGX/qtfNKr2G4v
bwIgL6D45UCXGozvLqnUc+fBVDir2Y8HwB+37LDor2yZGRkCIQCp6QqQXe66D+yx
oxIo88drS2IOiz8fwUxjlRiSVnjb2wIhAJg4TNnK/0kx5yUrd/dT88ekQ7Pp7md2
DqALeeYGX1gE
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

An equivalent result would be obtained with e.g.:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform pem -in <encrypted PKCS#8 key> -outform pem -nocrypt -out <PKCS#8 key>
```

---

For completeness: The encryption algorithm can be changed by the 4th parameter in [`openssl_pkey_export()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-export.php), e.g.:

```
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKeyEnc1, "12345678", array('encrypt_key_cipher' => OPENSSL_CIPHER_AES_256_CBC));
```

applies AES-256 in CBC mode instead of Triple DES in CBC mode.